# spring boot gradle plugin in a multi module project - error finding mainClass

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, build

I am using Spring boot gradle plugin version *1.5.1 RELEASE* as shown below. The build fails at webProject complaining about missing property '*mainClass*' and works only when I run '***webProject:build***'. Is this the expected usage?

**Edit**: Updated the build script and removed 'spring-boot' plugin from allProjects. Had to add 'bootRepackage' in web project as it was failing at this step - with the same error. Adding the 'bootRepackage' didn't help.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.1.RELEASE'
}

defaultTasks 'clean', 'build'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    //apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot' -- Commented out based on the answer
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        //all dependencies
    }
}

project('aProject') {
    dependencies {
        compile(project(':bProject'))

    }
}

project('webProject') {

    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    war {
        baseName = 'webProject'
        version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    dependencies {
        compile(project(':aproject'))
        compile(project(':bProject'))
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    springBoot {
        mainClass = 'com.abc.SomeApplication'
    }
bootRepackage{
    enabled = false
    mainClass = 'com.abc.SomeApplication'
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem in a multi module Spring boot project.
When compiling module A which doesn't have a main class. The main class is in a different module (module B).

I add a plugin in that module A's build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "module B.ITS_MAIN_CLASS"
```

Then it works.

Comment: though this response addressed my problem, I ended up using spring boot for all modules. Tried suggestion by luboskmac as well but no luck. ended up not using bootRun. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Spring Boot gradle plugin in main project, only in `webProject` sub-module.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the plugin from 'allprojects' war task was successful but repackage failed with the same error. I updated my question based on your inputs. Thanks